# Express wildcard routes cannot find routes with `?`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm still new to Express. I have a simple react ssr application that works well for an exact match route (/about, /cv, /contact) but fails for a path with a query string, even only with `?` in the end. For example `/cv?`

```
Cannot GET /cv
```

I'm using react-router for navigation. Here's the `server.tsx` code:

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import App from '../src/components/App'
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes, { Path } from '../src/shared/routes';
import Firebase from '../src/components/Firebase';
import firebaseInstance from '../src/components/Firebase/config';
import { determineUserLang } from '../src/shared/i18n';

const server = express();

server.use('/static', express.static('./build/static'));
server.use('/favicon.ico', express.static('./build/favicon.ico'));
server.use('/manifest.json', express.static('./build/manifest.json'));

server.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {

  const acceptsLanguages = req.acceptsLanguages();
  console.log('SERVER#acceptsLanguages', acceptsLanguages);
  const language = determineUserLang(acceptsLanguages);
  console.log('SERVER#language', language);

  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) =>
    matchPath(route.path, req.url)
  )

  const firebase = new Firebase(language, firebaseInstance.database());

  if (!activeRoute) {
    return next();
  }

  // We have check the for validity of the path,
  // so we can cast it to Path.
  const ourPath: Path = req.path as Path;
  console.log('req.path', req.path);
  console.log('ourPath', ourPath);

  activeRoute
    .fetchInitialData(ourPath, firebase)
    .then((initialData) => {

      console.log('data', initialData);
      console.log('data, stringify', JSON.stringify(initialData));

      const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
          <App initialData={initialData} />
        </StaticRouter>
      );
    
      const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');
    
      fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
          return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
        }
        return res.send(
          data
            .replace(
              '<div id="root"></div>', 
              `<div id="root">${app}</div>`
            )
            .replace(
              '<script id="initial-data"></script>', 
              `<script>
                window.__DATA__=${JSON.stringify(initialData)}
              </script>`
            )
        );
      });
    })
    .catch(next);
});
// Run on PORT 3002 unless SETOELKAHFI_COM_PORT is set
const port = process.env.SETOELKAHFI_COM_PORT || 3002;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Here's the `react-router` part:

```
           <Switch>
                {
                    routes.map((route, index) => (
                        <Route key={index} exact={route.exact} path={route.path} >
                            <route.component 
                                firebase={props.firebase} 
                                initialData={props.initialData} 
                            />
                        </Route>
                    ))
                }
            </Switch>
```

Removing the `exact={true}` makes client navigation doesn't work and it doesn't solve the problems as well.

This is the routes:

```
import Home from '../components/Home';
import About from '../components/About';
import React from 'react';
import { getAbout, getHome, getContact, getCv } from './api';
import Contact from '../components/Contact';
import Cv from '../components/Cv';
import Firebase from '../components/Firebase';

export interface Route {
    path: Path;
    component: React.ComponentType<any>;
    exact?: boolean;
    fetchInitialData: (path: Path, firebase: Firebase) => Promise<InitialData>;
}

export type InitialData = {
    data: any;
    path: Path;
}

export enum Path {
    HOME = '/',
    ABOUT = '/about',
    CONTACT = '/contact',
    CV = '/cv'
}

// Desc: Routes for the application
const routes: Route[]  = [
    {
        path: Path.HOME,
        component: Home,
        exact: true,
        fetchInitialData: getHome
    },
    {
        path: Path.ABOUT,
        component: About,
        fetchInitialData: getAbout
    },
    {
        path: Path.CONTACT,
        component: Contact,
        fetchInitialData: getContact
    },
    {
        path: Path.CV,
        component: Cv,
        fetchInitialData: getCv
    }
];

export default routes;
```

Any clue?

Comment: try removing the query string: `matchPath(route.path, req.originalUrl.split('?').shift())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this with this:

```
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => {
    const cleanUrl = req.url.split('?')[0];
    return matchPath(route.path, cleanUrl)
  })
```

Thanks to @traynor